# checking the main and subordinate powershell gui

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface

how to write code with a condition:if you click on the subsection checkbox, then the section checkbox is also selected, and vice versa, if you select a section, then all the sub-items are selected

[image]

I tried checking the node's checkbox but it works for the entire treewiew

Comment: $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$TreeView.width = 300
$TreeView.Height = 360
$treeView.CheckBoxes = $true
$TreeView.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120,100)

$main_form.Controls.add($TreeView)
$TreeViewNode1=$TreeView.Nodes.Add("DMD")

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).